# Рефлексия в С#, связь с атрибутами

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

На сколько мне известно под рефлексией понимается процесс выявления типов во время выполнения, и возможность, зная название методов, свойств, обращаться к ним.

```
MyClass myClassObj = new MyClass();
Type myTypeObj = myClassObj.GetType();
MethodInfo myMethodInfo = myTypeObj.GetMethod("Method");
```

но я часто слышал, что и работу некоторых атрибутов в C# относят к рефлексии, хотелось бы узнать, так ли это? И если так, то каких именно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, обычно атрибуты *используют* вместе с рефлексией для того, чтобы отмаркировать отдельные поля/свойства/методы. Судя по всему, именно это имелось в виду.

Вот типичный пример.

Объявляем атрибут `[Optional(value)]`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class OptionalAttribute : Attribute
{
    public OptionalAttribute(object defaultValue)
    {
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

В конструкторе базового класса обходим все свойства производного класса, и если у свойства выставлен атрибут, присваиваем начальное значение:

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes<OptionalAttribute>(true)
                                    .SingleOrDefault();
            if (attribute == null)
                continue;
            property.SetValue(this, attribute.DefaultValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Пользуемся:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    [Optional(3)]
    public int x { get; set; }
}

Console.WriteLine(new Derived().X); // 3
```